# QuerySyntaxException Invalid path + JPA + Hibernate 5.4

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get the total row count based on the CriteriaQuery but got an exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.package.id' [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.test.Product as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias1.package.id like :param0 )]
```

**Code**

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = session().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> entity = query.from(Product.class);
query.where(where_clause);

CriteriaQuery<Long> queryCount = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Product> entity = queryCount.from(query.getResultType());
queryCount.where(query.getRestriction()) -- this is where the problem is creating
```

**Entity**

```
class Product{
Package package;
int quantity;

/// getter setter method

}

class Package{
String id;
String name;
String type

/// getter setter method
```

}

mapping is done using hbm xml file.

can you please let me know how to fix it ?

Comment: Could you please provide sql that will show what you want to achieve.

Comment: @SternK the query should create like select count(generatedAlias0) from com.test.Product as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.package.id like :param0 )

Comment: Could you please also show your entity `Product` mapping.

Comment: @SternK updated. can you please tell me how I can use all the conditions I am using for query in queryCount ? queryCount.where(query.getRestriction()) -- this line is creating a different alias name which is creating the issue,

Answer (score 10):

You have two different queries. So you can't use the same predicate for both of them, because they have different roots.

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path:
> 'generatedAlias1.package.id' [select count(generatedAlias0) from
> com.test.Product as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias1.package.id
> like :param0 )]

`generatedAlias1` is alias for `Product` from another query

To make the predicate reusable you should create method returns predicate

```
Predicate getPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaBuilder builder, Parameter param) {
   // returns predicate using root, builder and param you need
   return builder.equal(root.get("fieldName"), param);
}
```

And then use it in queries

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = session().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> entity = query.from(Product.class);
query.where(getPredicate(entity, cb, param));

CriteriaBuilder cbCount = session().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> queryCount = cbCount.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Product> entityCount = queryCount.from(Product.class);
queryCount.where(getPredicate(entityCount, cbCount, param));
```

Comment: thanks. yes, I got that and so I changed the code and used two different queries.