# Criteria API count query get "Error occurred validating the Criteria"

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I'm going to add a count query to my working Criteria API implements,

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Account> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Account.class);
//THIS IS I'm going to add
CriteriaQuery<Long> cqCount = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Account> accountRoot = query.from(Account.class);
/**
bunch of predicate code
**/
//The original code with Predicate List
query.where(pre);

//THIS IS I'm going to add
cqCount.select(criteriaBuilder.count(accountRoot));
cqCount.where(pre);
TypedQuery<Long> typedQueryCount = entityManager.createQuery(cqCount);
Long count = typedQueryCount.getSingleResult();
//above is the added code

//the original code
TypedQuery<Account> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(accountFilterInfoDto.getCount());
List<Account> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

However I get

> Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred validating the Criteria]

What could be wrong?
Removing the added count code works alright.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly this problem. Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724669/6922320

The problem is, the same predicate is used for the two different queries. This is not allowed. This could be moved to a method and just called for both DB queries.

Also, the roots must be different (even if they are gotten from the same entity) since they are produced from different criteriaQueries. (You may also see: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination, noticed difference roots)